# How to kill a dead screen session?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Originally posted in [Unix and Linux community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343052/how-to-kill-dead-screen-session) but no correct answer after a couple of days. I will move the answer there if I get the answer from here. Thanks!

How do I kill a *dead* screen session?

```
[allen@mmbp ~]$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    3634.wb_backend (Dead ???)
Remove dead screens with 'screen -wipe'.
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-allen.
```

I tried `screen -X -S 3634.wb_backend quit` and here is the result:

```
There is a screen on:
3634.wikibrain_backend  (Dead ???)
Remove dead screens with 'screen -wipe'.
No screen session found.
```

I tried `screen -S -X wb_backend kill` and here is the result:

`mkfifo /var/run/screen/S-allen/27272.-X failed`

This (Dead ???) session used to be an Attached session and I used:

```
screen -X -S 3634.wb_backend kill
```

to kill it. It ended up to be in this weird status.

I have tried:

```
screen -wipe
```

but it didn't work.

How could I terminate it?

Answer (score 7):

```
screen -wipe PID
```

will wipe the dead screen.

Comment: thanks, i just didnt want to have it wipe the screen i needed.  i found the screen id, which i guess matches the PID, and ran it that way as you suggested and it only killed the dead screen session.

Answer (score 5):

You need to kill the PID as reported by `screen -ls`, then wipe the session:

```
kill -9 3634
screen -wipe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a kill command to the specific screen session.

E.g.

> [allen@mmbp ~]$ screen -ls
>
> There is a screen on:
>
> 3634.wb_backend (Dead ???)
>
> Remove dead screens with 'screen -wipe'.
>
> 1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-allen.

You would just kill the specific PID

```
kill 3634
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It ended up to be a insufficient disk space problem - the hard disk went into read-only mode.

Answer (score -1):

I am using putty, and it seems I am already in the screen and couldn't open and close. Every time I do "exit", I just close the putty window. Here is the termimal print

`>>screen -r`

```
    21063.unlimited (11/08/20 15:45:19)     (Attached)
    24054.cure6     (11/08/20 09:46:13)     (Attached)
```

`There is no screen to be resumed.`
and

`screen -S 21063.unlimited -X stuff $'\003'`

does not do anything.
I found that as simple as the following line works perfect

`screen -x 21063.unlimited`

it sends me back into the screen and from there "exit" works.
Note that it is lower-case `-x`

Comment: What does `screen -d -r 21063` do?